# XDEBUG 2.3.3 not showing in phpinfo() no matter what (XAMPP 1.8.2 PHP 5.4.31 )

Tags: php, eclipse, xampp, xdebug

I've read every post out there (I think), and after 2 days hunting this I am still stuck. The goal is to use xDebug with **Eclipse**, but I cannot get past loading xDebug in the first place.

I am using **XAMPP 1.8.2** with **PHP 5.4.31**, and per XDEBUG analyzer (below) downloaded the file suggested.

> Tailored Installation Instructions
>
> Summary
>
> Xdebug installed: no
>      Server API: Apache 2.0 Handler
>      Windows: yes - Compiler: MS VC9 - Architecture: x86
>      Zend Server: no
>      PHP Version: 5.4.31
>      Zend API nr: 220100525
>      PHP API nr: 20100525
>      Debug Build: no
>      Thread Safe Build: yes
>      Configuration File Path: C:\Windows
>      Configuration File: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
>      Extensions directory: C:\xampp\php\ext
>
> Instructions
>
> Download php_xdebug-2.3.3-5.4-vc9.dll
>      Move the downloaded file to C:\xampp\php\ext
>      Edit C:\xampp\php\php.ini and add the line
>      zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.3.3-5.4-vc9.dll
>      Restart the webserver

I have edited **php.ini** in my XAMPP (*located in C:\xampp*) with the following:

> [XDebug]
>      zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.3.3-5.4-vc9.dll
>      xdebug.remote_enable = 1
>      xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
>      xdebug.remote_host = "localhost"
>      xdebug.remote_port = 9001

I see no errors in any logs for my Apache server. What am I missing?

Comment: The output of `<?php echo get_cfg_var('cfg_file_path');` confirms c:\xampp\php.ini to be the correct php.ini ? Did you also check the php log file specified in the php.ini as `error_log=....`?

Comment: Thank you. That was the issue. I had copied the php.ini in the incorrect directory and was editing it!